# Change default search criteria in Vim

Tags: vim

I'm looking for a way to change the **default criteria pattern** Search in Vim

For example:
You can search the word under the cursor

```
Shift-*
```

**My problem:**

When there is a string `"my_name"` in my file and if `"name"` is under my cursor in a different string and I do the search in Vim with `Shift-*`

Substring `"name"` is not highlighted in `"my_name"`

It seems to me Vim default criteria pattern matching is not included '_' as a word character, please correct me if I'm wrong.

**What I did so far.**

I read some help Doc. such as [:h hlsearch] and [:h search].
But I still can't figure out how to change the default search pattern.

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: See `:help 'iskeyword'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the following in your `.vimrc`

```
set iskeyword+=_
```

Answer (score 1):

I would advise not to change the iskeyword setting. Instead use the `g*` command, that will find also submatches and does not restrict the match to be at the word boundary. So while `*` searches for `\<name\>` <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>*</kbd> searches for `name` and will therefore find submatches.